# User profile request returning NULL

Tags: zend-framework, youtube-api

I'm having a problem with a YouTube profile request.  I think it relates to a user who has linked Google accounts.

Our system has a process for authorising YouTube accounts.  Once a user has authorised our system, we use the access token to retrieve the user's default profile, to check it's actually the account we were expecting to be authorised, which has worked fine for most users, but for one user, the request for to https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default (using the PHP Zend library's ->getUserProfile() method) is returning NULL for this one user. I think it might be because they have a main Google Apps accounts, without a YouTube channel, & also a different YouTube channel (listed in the YouTube account menu when you click 'Switch Accounts').

We have tried using a Safari private browser & a Chrome incognito browser but neither of these seem to work.

Does anyone know why this might be, & how I go about checking the profile for each of the user's linked profiles/accounts?

Answer (score 0):

Not every account has a unique username, you should not depend on usernames but instead on channel ids.

From [API documents](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids):

The biggest takeaway for developers using the older Data API v2 is that you must be aware that not every YouTube channel has a unique username. Fortunately, every YouTube channel is guaranteed to have a unique channel ID associated with it, represented by the value in the `<yt:channelId>` tag, and that’s the value that we recommend developers use instead of usernames. For instance, if you have a database that maps YouTube usernames to information about that channel, your older entries should continue to work. (Existing channels won’t lose their usernames.) However, as time goes on, it will become more and more likely that you’ll have to work with channels that can’t be uniquely identified by a username.

A couple of factors simplify the transition from usernames to channel IDs. First, the Data API v2 accepts channel IDs in request URLs wherever it accepts YouTube usernames, meaning that you can seamlessly swap a channel ID into your existing code. For example, since UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw is the channel ID for the channel with the legacy username GoogleDevelopers, the following two URLs are equivalent API requests:

`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers?v=2.1`
`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw?v=2.1`

Another thing to keep in mind is that whenever you’re making authenticated v2 requests, you never need to include the authorized channel’s username when constructing request URLs. You can always use the value default in place of a username (or channel ID). So if you want to retrieve the video uploads feed for the currently authorized user, for instance, you can do so at https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads?v=2.1.